# CentOS extend home partition multiple times

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, partition

I allow my clients to ask an unlimited number of times to extend the hard drive. Although, after 2 times, there is no physical volumes left to create. How can I still extend sda1 or sda2? Is it possible to combine sda1 and sda3? (A bit like on windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what MBR logical partitions are for. Also, you should probably be using LVM if you need this level of flexibility.